# Devise - 'create' action of overridden SessionsController not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following configuration in my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions"}
```

I'm trying to override the 'create' method of the sessions controller with no luck. It's never being called.
The 'new' action of the same controller gets called.

Routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format) sessions#new
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format) sessions#create
```

Any idea?

Comment: Post your login form & your custom session controller.

Comment: @farleyknight I found the problem, see my answer. Thanx for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I had a `before_filter` in my `application_controller.rb` which raised a CanCan::AccessDenied error by mistake. 
Why did this cause to execute the method from the "original" devise controller??? No idea...

I fixed the error in the filter and everything seems to be ok, my overriden action is executed.